# Stringified JSON wont become string and wont parse in localstorage

Tags: javascript

I am using @ionic/storage `set` and `get` commands.

In one component I am setting a JSON object `await set('currentConversation', JSON.stringify(response));`

In the other component i am retreiving the key and checking what it looks like `const conversationResource = await get('currentConversation'); console.log('CHAT PAGE CONVERSATIONG FROM STORAGE', JSON.parse(conversationResource))`

What I see is one JSON object displayed correctly in the the console, and one JSON object (the one i turned into a string, not actually a string, but just a big mess.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You should not use `JSON.Stringify` with a `Response` object, and to drive that point home you'll see that it also _doesn't work_, that's because `Stringify` only serializes "owned" and enumerable properties - and `Response` has none of those.

Comment: if the storage needs a string, whats the protocol?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question - you need to understand what a `Response` object is under-the-hood first (generally speaking: it encapsulates the browser's own native/internal response data), that's why you shouldn't serialize it.

Comment: interesting. so i should try to extract the part i need and serialize that?

Comment: I think what you **really** want is to save the JSON response body? If so, why are you serializing it? Just save `const jsonBody = await response.text()` instead. You can always `JSON.parse(jsonBody)` afterwards (as you can't call `await response.json()` after `.text()`.

Comment: Also, `localStorage.set` does not return a `Promise` so there's no point using `await` with it.